# including <netinet/tcp_var.h> error: field has incomplete type 'struct xsocket'

Tags: c++, tcp

The project I am working with has the following includes

```
#include <memory.h>
#include <signal.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/sysctl.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#ifdef __linux__
#  include <linux/tcp.h>
#else
#  include <sys/time.h>
#  include <netinet/in.h>
#  include <netinet/tcp.h>
#  include <netinet/tcp_var.h>
#endif
```

I am compiling on a 64-bit mac.  When the tcp_var.h include is reached the compiler throws the following errors:

```
/usr/include/netinet/in_pcb.h:192:17: error: field has incomplete type 'struct xsocket'
        struct  xsocket xi_socket;
                        ^
/usr/include/netinet/in_pcb.h:192:9: note: forward declaration of 'xsocket'
        struct  xsocket xi_socket;
                ^
/usr/include/netinet/in_pcb.h:235:20: error: field has incomplete type 'struct xsocket64'
        struct  xsocket64 xi_socket;
                          ^
/usr/include/netinet/in_pcb.h:235:10: note: forward declaration of 'xsocket64'
        struct  xsocket64 xi_socket;
                ^
/usr/include/netinet/in_pcb.h:245:2: error: unknown type name 'so_gen_t'
        so_gen_t        xig_sogen;      /* current socket generation count */
        ^
In file included from .../tcp_client_listener.cc:52:
/usr/include/netinet/tcp_var.h:373:25: error: field has incomplete type 'struct xsocket'
        struct  xsocket xt_socket;
                        ^
/usr/include/netinet/in_pcb.h:192:9: note: forward declaration of 'xsocket'
        struct  xsocket xi_socket;
                ^
/Users/Justin/Projects/smartdevicelink/SDL_Core/src/components/transport_manager/src/tcp/tcp_client_listener.cc:141:44: error: use of undeclared identifier
      'TCP_USER_TIMEOUT'
    setsockopt(connection_fd, IPPROTO_TCP, TCP_USER_TIMEOUT, &user_timeout, sizeof(user_timeout));
```

Is there a different library that I can include between `#ifdef MAC_OSX` directives or a way to fix this forward declaration and maintain compatibility with other macs?

Answer (score 1):

it's all about the order in which you import the headers!

this order works

```
#import <sys/socketvar.h>
#import <netinet/in.h>
#import <netinet/tcp_var.h>
#import <netinet/tcp.h>
#import <sys/socket.h>
```

Comment: @standy both work, but right I try to use #include for C and C++ headers and #import for objective c

Answer (score -2):

use

```
 #include <sys/socket.h>
```

in else part

Comment: yes add that line, i am not fame-lier with mac. add socketvar.h